# $.toggle() all instances of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to toggle hide show comments, I originally had it working just fine, because i thew all my comments inside of a single div with class `.forum-comments`.

However, now I am breaking up each comment with divs that have `.forum-comments` class

This is the original code:

```
   // Button dynamic comment show
    $("#forum").delegate(".btn-forum-comment-show", "click", function() {
      $(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();
      var change = $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").text();
      var show = '<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show';
      var hide = '<i class="icon-minus-sign icon-white"></i> hide';
      if(change == ' show')
      {
        $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").html(hide);
      }
      if(change == ' hide')
      {
        $(this).parent().find(".btn-forum-comment-show").html(show);
      }
    });
```

the function `$(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();` stopped working as i have each comment with the `.forum-comments` class. So it only toggles the first comment on and off. the rest remain unaffected. How can i change this behavior so that each comment is toggled.?

html

```
    <div class="forum-comments" >
      <div class="forum-author">By: Jared De La Cruz on Sunday, July 07, 2013 7:31:20 PM</div>
      <div class="forum-owner">aae15c3ff2cf790b2c7fb61dbf1a83bfadbc59762622c4b39e25ba7e5fe434fd</div>
      <pre class="forum-body">yay comments!</pre>
      <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-forum-comment-del-comment" id=""><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="forum-comments" >
      <div class="forum-author">By: Jared De La Cruz on Tuesday, July 09, 2013 1:17:40 PM</div>
      <div class="forum-owner">aae15c3ff2cf790b2c7fb61dbf1a83bfadbc59762622c4b39e25ba7e5fe434fd</div>
      <pre class="forum-body">2nd comment1</pre>
      <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-forum-comment-del-comment" id=""><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> delete</a></div>
    </div>
```

these comments by default are hidden with `style="display:none"` and with `$.toggle()` are enabled/disabled

here is a dump of the entire section:

```
<div class="forum-post">
        <div><span class="forum-title">Welcome to the forum!</span><span class="forum-type label label-forum-Discussion">Discussion</span></div>
        <div class="forum-author">By: Jared De La Cruz on Sunday, July 07, 2013 7:31:08 PM</div>
        <div class="forum-owner">aae15c3ff2cf790b2c7fb61dbf1a83bfadbc59762622c4b39e25ba7e5fe434fd</div>
        <pre>This is the student forum, where any student can post information with the option to add tags!</pre>
        <div class="btn-group"><a id="" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-forum-comment-del"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> delete</a></div>
        <div class="btn-group"><a id="" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary btn-forum-comment"><i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i> comment</a></div>
        <div class="btn-group"><a id="" class="btn btn-mini btn-inverse btn-forum-comment-show"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> show</a></div>
        <div class="forum-comments" style="display: block;">
            <div class="forum-author">By: Jared De La Cruz on Sunday, July 07, 2013 7:31:20 PM</div>
            <div class="forum-owner">aae15c3ff2cf790b2c7fb61dbf1a83bfadbc59762622c4b39e25ba7e5fe434fd</div>
            <pre class="forum-body">yay comments!</pre>
            <div class="btn-group"><a id="" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-forum-comment-del-comment"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> delete</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="forum-comments">
            <div class="forum-author">By: Jared De La Cruz on Tuesday, July 09, 2013 1:17:40 PM</div>
            <div class="forum-owner">aae15c3ff2cf790b2c7fb61dbf1a83bfadbc59762622c4b39e25ba7e5fe434fd</div>
            <pre class="forum-body">2nd comment1</pre>
            <div class="btn-group"><a id="" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger btn-forum-comment-del-comment"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-white"></i> delete</a></div>
        </div>
        <hr style="border-top: 1px dotted #b0b0b0;border-bottom: 0px">
    </div>
```

UPDATE: sovled with creating a new classes `.forum-comments` and `.forum-comment` with

`var post = $(this).parents(".forum-comment");`

and

`$(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: Looks like a job for `.each()` at first glance. See http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: wheres your .btn-forum-comment-show

Comment: `.btn-forum-comment-show` is one step above this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `nextAll` instead of `next`

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".forum-comments").toggle();
```

check the [document](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line

```
$(this).parent().next(".forum-comments").toggle();
```

with

```
var $parent = $(this).parent();
$parent.next(".forum-comments").length ? $parent.next(".forum-comments").toggle()
                                       : $parent.prev(".forum-comments").toggle()
```

The last comment section will not work as `$parent.next(".forum-comments")` will evaluate to an empty selector. So it will not work in such cases

Comment: this did not work for me it still only toggles 1, becuase `.forum-comments` only contains 1 comment. i have multiple comments